# custom edit button in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have added add custom button in jqgrid but not able to pass custom button for edit adding custom button for add please help me adding custom edit button.

```
.jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#list_translation_toppager_left',{
                    caption:"",
                    buttonicon:"ui-icon-plus",
                    onClickButton:function(){
                                                    console.log($(st_trans).html());
                                                if($(st_trans).html() != null ) {
                            maintab_trans.tabs('select',st_trans);
                            $(st_trans).empty();
                            //cosole.log("no");
                        }
                        maintab_trans.tabs('remove',st_trans);
                        maintab_trans.tabs('add',st_trans, treedata_trans.menu);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "php/xxx.html",
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "html",
                            complete : function (req, err) {
                                $(st_trans,"#tabs").append(req.responseText);
                                //console.log(st_trans);
                                //console.log(treedata_trans);
                                jQuery(".ui-widget-content").css({'height':'70%'});
                                jQuery("#gbox_west-grid").css({'height':''});
                                jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-view").css({'height':'90%'});
                                jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").css({'height':'85%'});
                                try { var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-5463047-4"); pageTracker._trackPageview(); } catch(err) {};
                            }
                        });


                                    },
                    position: "first",
                    title:"",
                    cursor: "pointer"

            } );
```